# Add slug in the URL filament Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-filament

I have `PostResource` in my filament application.

Post modal schema

```
Posts
    - id
    - title
    - slug
    - description
    - created_by
    - status
```

Now, whenever I create a new post and it redirects to the Edit page and URL accessing like `http://127.0.0.1"8000/posts/1/edit`.
but can we add a slug in the URL?

Excepted URL: `http://127.0.0.1"8000/posts/<SLUG>/edit`

In my `PostResource` the routes

```php
public static function getPages(): array
{
    return [
        'index' => Pages\ListPosts::route('/'),
        'create' => Pages\CreatePost::route('/create'),
        // here, it binding route model, I want to change with slug
        'edit' => Pages\EditPost::route('/{record}/edit'),
    ];
}
```

Comment: You should read basic Laravel documentation

Comment: @SiZE, I know how we can set the slug in the route, but it's a TALL Stack Filament. and I am trying to implement in the Filament that works with the route model binding by default

Comment: @SiZE it's a filament question, not about core Laravel.

Comment: @KhyatiBhojawala There are features in core Laravel that Filament will happily use. In this case, you want to look into `getRouteKey` and `getRouteKeyName` for your Eloquent models rather than having to manually `url()` every time.

Comment: @ceejayoz , Thanks for the guidance; would you please share any example for the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple, is that...

In your `PostResource` you need to add `->url()` and as a route parameter add `$record->slug`.

```php
Tables\Actions\EditAction::make()
    ->url(fn (Model $record): string => static::getUrl('edit', ['record' => $record->slug])),
```

### Updated - 28-06-2023

---

If you change the slug in the clickable `tr`, you need to change it in your List class and override the `getTableRecordUrlUsing()` function.

`PlanResource > Pages > ListPlans`

```php
use Closure;

class ListPlans extends ListRecords
{
    // ...
    
    protected function getTableRecordUrlUsing(): ?Closure
    {
        return function (Model $record): ?string {
            foreach (['view', 'edit'] as $action) {
                $action = $this->getCachedTableAction($action);

                if (! $action) {
                    continue;
                }

                $action->record($record);

                if ($action->isHidden()) {
                    continue;
                }

                $url = $action->getUrl();

                if (! $url) {
                    continue;
                }

                return $url;
            }

            $resource = static::getResource();

            foreach (['view', 'edit'] as $action) {
                if (! $resource::hasPage($action)) {
                    continue;
                }

                if (! $resource::{'can' . ucfirst($action)}($record)) {
                    continue;
                }
                // here you need to add slug
                return $resource::getUrl($action, ['record' => $record->slug]);
            }

            return null;
        };
    }
}
```